# change() function not working with selected value

Tags: jquery, html

If I select the selected option text " A " the change() function is not working. But if I select some other like B,C its work fine and after that if I select the A its work nicely.Why its not working in beginning.Is it possible to triggered the function . Please help

```js
$('#type').change(function() {
  var val = $('#type option:selected ').val();
  alert(val);
})

$(function() {
  $('#type').val('1');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
  <option >--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Option `A` is already selected because of `$('#type').val('1');`. So if you select that value, you're not changing anything, and the `.change()` event isn't triggered.

Comment: Also note that the `change` event handler should really be inside the `document.ready` handler

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do what you want. You can use `.mouseup`, but it executes before the selection is changed, so you alert the old value. You can use `.blur`, but then you have to click on something else to trigger it.

Comment: BTW, you can simplify `$('#type option:selected ').val();` to just `$("#type").val()`

Comment: @Barmar how to use .blur in this case

Comment: `$('#type').blur(...)` with the same function.

Comment: But its not work without a click another problem

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to keep track on whether the select is open, and if, and someone also clicked on it, you call a function

In addition, you save the current value in an attribute and then compare in the `mouseup` event if they are the same, and if, you trigger the `change` event manually, as the `change` event won't fire by itself since the user clicked the same option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var isOpen = false;

  // Init any selection
  $('#type').attr('data-val', $('#type').val());

  $('#type').change(function() {
    selectWasClicked($(this).val());
  })

  $('#type').mouseup(function() {
    if (!(isOpen)) {
      isOpen = true;
      return;
    }
    isOpen = false;
    if ($(this).attr('data-val') == $(this).val()) {
      $(this).trigger("change");
    }
    $(this).attr('data-val', $(this).val());
  })

  $('#type').blur(function() {
    isOpen = false;
  })

  function selectWasClicked(val) {
    console.log('someone clicked on the select value: ', val);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="type">
  <option >--Select--</option>
  <option value="1" selected>A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that is not my ans

Comment: @AjayKrishnaDutta Updated my answer. If this does not answer your question, please add some more info what is missing or wrong